# Procmail autoresponse to a single sender (or few ones)

Tags: postfix, sendmail, procmail

I've been looking some similar examples and slight changes to them to perform that but unsuccessfully.
This is the first recipe at $HOME/.procmailrc of the user "me".
Mail is received by user@domain.tld but the auto response is not sent.
Centos 7, Postfix
procmail log doesn't say anything about that.

```
:0
* ^FROMuser@domain.tld
* !^FROM_DAEMON
* !^FROM_MAILER
* !^X-Loop: me@me.tld
| (formail -rk \
    -A "X-Loop: me@me.tld" \
    -A "Precedence: junk"; \
    echo "Testing";\
    echo "This is an automated response";\
    echo "Not sure to see your message";\
    echo "So please try again tomorrow" ) | $SENDMAIL -t -oi
```

Comment: I found similar thing on [howto forge](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-postfix-autoresponder-with-autorespons/) maybe it might help you

Comment: Link is 404. At howtoforge.com I tried search by "autorespons","autoreply","vacation", "procmail" with no results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the structure of the second line `* ^FROMuser@domain.tld` from , page suggested in another [question/answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/282859/setting-up-procmail-to-ignore-auto-responders-and-bounces) in SeverFault.

I simply changed that by `* ^From.*user@domain.tld` and it worked

Comment: Indeed, `^FROMuser@domain.tld` would simply look in the headers for this exact string (after the `^`, except `.` matches any character) at beginning of line, which is not fundamentally impossble, but not something you would ever see in reality.

Comment: can you please refer the answers from serverfault.com which you mean?

Comment: @djdomi Done, added to the question

Comment: Great, dont forgot to accept your answer later on